# Remove thousand separator C-programming

Tags: c

Im trying to make a simple function which can convert a number with a thousand separator to an integer without the separator. All my numbers are within the range of 0 to 999.999, so my initial though was to just handle it like a double and then multiply it by 1000 and call it a day, but is there a more generel way of doing this?:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
    double a;
    a=369.122;
    int b;
    b = a * 1000;
    printf("b is %d", b);
}
```

Where is my current solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {

    char *XD = "113.321";

    int s1, s2;

    sscanf(XD, "%i.%i", &s1, &s2);
    printf("%i", s1 * 1000 + s2);
}
```

Comment: You don't want to do that... You might overflow `b`.

Answer (score 4):

Using a `double` for this is not appropriate due to floating point imprecision: you might find that when multiplied by 1000 and truncate to an `int`, you end up with a number that is 1 less than you really want.

Also note that the largest value for an `int` can be as small as 32767. On such a platform, you would overflow `b`.

If I were you, I'd use a `long` throughout and introduce the 1000s separator when you want to display the value. For a positive number `x`, the first 1000 is attained using `x / 1000`, the final 1000 using `x % 1000`.

Comment: I've got a CSV-file with numbers where one of the fields is a count of the spectators at a specific football game. In the file, which im not allowed to edit, the number is listed using the separator. How would you convert the '6.185' to the integer 6185?

Comment: @TobiasKnudsen 1) If you're parsing the CSV, remove the thousands separator *in the string* (before you've converted it to a number) as part of parsing. 2) Maybe you're not allowed to *edit* the CSV, but you can create a working copy that is convenient to parse (e.g. without thousands separators).

Comment: Thanks guys: I'm going to give it a go, and then i'll update my question with the solution!

Comment: Cool, but don't update the question; feel free to *answer* your own question when you have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply parse the input yourself and ignore the separators.
Parsing integers is easy:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c;
    unsigned n = 0, acc = 0;
    while(EOF!=(c=getchar())){
        if(c>='0' && c<='9')
           acc = 10*n + c-'0';
        else if(c == '.') //ignore your separator
            continue;
        else 
            break; //not a digit and not a separator -- end parsing
        if(acc < n)   
            fprintf(stderr, "overflow\n");
        n =  acc;
    }
    printf("got %d\n", n);
}
```

If you want very hi-perf., avoid the `getchar` and parse a buffered string (or at least use `getchar_unlocked`).

Alternatively, you can lex the string, copy legal characters to a buffer, and then run strtoul or similar on that buffer.

You should only only need like 22 characters for the buffer max (assuming base 10) or else 64 bit integers would start overflowing if you parsed them from a buffer that needed more digits.

Answer (score 0):

A rugged, generic solution is to use a string, then simply skip everything that is not a digit. That way you don't have to worry about locale etc. (Several countries use `,` for decimals and `.` for thousand separator, while English-speaking counties do the opposite. And spaces are also sometimes used for thousand separator.)

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uint32_t digits_only (const char* str_number)
{
  uint32_t result = 0;

  for(size_t i=0; str_number[i] != '\0'; i++)
  {
    if(isdigit(str_number[i]))
    {
      result *= 10;
      result += (uint32_t)str_number[i] - '0';
    }
  }

  return result;
}

int main (void)
{
  printf("%" PRIu32 "\n", digits_only("123,456"));
  printf("%" PRIu32 "\n", digits_only("123.456"));
  printf("%" PRIu32 "\n", digits_only("blabla 123 blabla 456 blabla"));
}
```